# Torch C++: API to check NAN

Tags: pytorch, torch, libtorch

I am using libtorch C++. In python version we can easily check the value of a tensor by calling its `numpy` value, and in `numpy` we have `np.isnan()`. I was wondering if there is a built in function in `libtorch` `C++` to check whether a tensor has any `NAN` value?

Thanks,
Afshin

Comment: if `x` is `NaN` then `x != x` is `True`...

Comment: Got it. I found the code in the unreleased version which uses this idea.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to Fábio's answer (my reputation is too low to comment):

If you actually want to use the information about NANs in an `assert` or `if` condition you need convert it from a `torch::Tensor` to a C++ `bool` like so

```
torch::Tensor myTensor;
// do something
auto tensorIsNan = at::isnan(myTensor).any().item<bool>(); // will be of type bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`at::isnan`](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/function_namespaceat_1aa468b5546791b20fa71d2fb1b797ecdc.html).

```
int main() {
  torch::Tensor tensor = torch::rand({2, 3});
  std::cout << tensor << std::endl;
  std::cout << at::isnan(tensor) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Note: I had to install the nightly build of libtorch since the stable release did not have `isnan`.

Comment: Do you have any idea when it would be added to the stable version?

Comment: I checked with them and I will be in 1.1. Probably I will implement one function for myself.